# Unity: input axis raw for touch returning fractions

Tags: unity, input, touch

I am not going to show any script, which may make it complicated. In unity ,when I used the cross platform input manager for touch buttons, the raw axis values returned are in small fractions(like 0.4321,0.1123) sometimes even smaller values, like 1.2322e-10. I want the value to be 1(when keypressed) or 0(when keyreleased). Where am I going wrong, what should I do then?

The function I used
CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")

Comment: Why are you using raw axis values for buttons? This doesn't sound like the right tool for the job. It would be best if you could show us an example of how you're trying to use this method, so we can suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That returns the **coordinate** of the touches, not whether someone is touching the game. Check if it's larger, then 0 to check if it's being held